# How to show a toast when user click a disabled checkbox in android

Tags: android, user-interface, checkbox

I don't want the click event change the status of `checkbox`.Instead, I want to show a `toast`. So I use `checkbox.setEnabled`(false), but I can't show the `toast` if I do this. I don't have any ideas now

Comment: Use OnTouchListener

Comment: If you don't want users to change the value of the checkbox, then you disable it. Users know when a checkbox is disabled, so they won't click it.

Comment: @ammcom That doesn't work for disabled controls I think. Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, I used onTouchListener and solved my problem, thanks

Comment: In fact, I used OnClickListener

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's bad UX to do what you want.

People should be able to see that your checkbox is disabled from its color for example. They don't expect to be able to interact with it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, now I just want to keep the status of  the checkbox(disable the click effect) and show a toast when user clicks it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That's what I mean when I say it's bad UX. There should be no interaction with the user. Not even a toast.

Answer (score 0):

Use OnTouchListener For the whole activity then detect the action is Touch down and check the coordinates so that it conform to the checkbox position

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        //check e.getX() and e.getY() so that it is inside the checkbox area
        return true; //only if the touch is on the check box 
        //return false otherwise
    }
    return false;
}
});
```